# Add temporary attribute to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I start to learn ruby on rails and I want to temporary add an attribute to a model so I added the accessor to my model :

```
attr_accessor :dettes
```

And then I used the method `each`, here is what I have :

```
@depenses = Depense.where(user_id: @user.id)
@depenses.each do |d|
  d.dettes =  "value"
end
render json: @depenses
```

But this didn't work, my new attribute isn't added

I've seen others questions about this but I'm still not able to resolve this, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `render :json` only adds the permanent attributes. You can add the temporary one as well this way:

```
render json: @depenses, methods: :dettes
```

Comment: Oh ok I see thanks ! Is that the same as  `@depenses.to_json(:methods => [:dettes])` ?

Comment: Yep, same thing! Render :json calls .to_json on whatever object it's rendering. And :methods takes an array of items, but if you only have one item, you can pass it in without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want modify object within request without mutating it in the database, so you add attr_accessor. 
Then you used

```
@depenses = Depense.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

Which returns instance of ActiveRecord::Relation(not explicit instances of objects which you can modify). So you when you iterates within this relation instance and change it attr_accessor the instance of modyfied object hasn't been assigned to any public variable. Basically you need to convert relation to array, then @depenses going to be an array of Depense instance objects, which you can modify and pass to render methods:

```
@depenses = Depense.where(user_id: @user.id).to_a
```

Then you need tell json that you want to use custom method for serializing, like @eiko mentioned:

```
render json: @depenses, methods: :dettes
```

(But if you have a loot of data in Depense datatable then it's not the best idea, you gonna use some limitations with offsets for where clause)

Keep rocking ;)